# How to access the Asp.net Previouspage object when redirecting using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here's some background info:

- Page 1: Contains a text box
- Page 2: Contains a label

If I do a `Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx")` I can easily access the text box on Page1.aspx by using `PreviousPage.TextboxRef` and assign its value to the label on Page2. No problems here. Everything works as expected.

However, if I do a JS redirect like this:

`window.location.href = "Page2.aspx";`

The PreviousPage object on Page2 is `null`. I have tried writing a function that does a "post" instead, but that still results with the same issue.

I also tried checking the `Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()` value and it is coming back correctly as Page1.aspx.

I'm sure it's something simple, but alas; I'm a noob.

I have searched for a solution with no success, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Comment: Thanks! It does make it a lot easier to read ; )

Comment: Well, you can't. If you use JavaScript to redirect, `PreviousPage` will always be `null`. All the states are lost since they are 2 completely different languages.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but I was hoping there was some cool secret way to do it ; ) Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do something like this in javascript where you are setting url.

```
window.location.href = "Page2.aspx?txt1Value="+document.getElementById('txt1Value').value;
```

and on other page you can get it using querystring in c#

```
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["txt1Value"];
```